# Introduction to analysis

Tags: real-analysis

I am trying to figure out this this question but I don't understand it. Can someone help me?

> Prove: for every real number $x>5$, there exists a real number $y<0$ such that $x=\frac{5y}{y+3}$.

Comment: Can you tell us what you've tried so far?

Comment: I don't have anything because I don't understAnd it

Answer (score 2):

Before the formal proof, we need to do some scratch work. Let's say $x=\frac{5y}{y+3}$. Then with a little algebra:

$$
x(y+3)=5y\\
xy+3x=5y\\
xy-5y=-3x\\
y(x-5)=-3x\\
y=\frac{-3x}{x-5}\\
$$

The reason we want to isolate $y$ is to show that given any real number $x$, there is another real number $y$ that is dependent on $x$.

Now onto the formal proof.

Given any real number $x$, there must be a real number $y$ such that $y=\frac{-3x}{x-5}$, because $\mathbb{R}$ is closed under the four "basic" operations. What remains to be shown is that if $x>5$ then this $y$, namely, $\frac{-3x}{x-5}$, is less than 0.

My approach is to analyze the numerator and denominator separately. You may wish to take a different approach.

If $x > 5$, then $-3x < -15$, so certainly $-3x < 0$ ($-3x$ is negative).

Additionally, if $x > 5$, then $x-5 > 0$ ($x-5$ is positive).

Therefore $\frac{-3x}{x-5}$ is the quotient of a negative number and a positive number. Since a negative divided by a positive is negative, it must be true that $\frac{-3x}{x-5} < 0$.

*q.e.d.*